# PHP Performance - Software Design - similar_text() for lots long strings

Tags: php, sql

I have 75,000+ texts stored in my database, each with 10,000+ characters.

Approximately every two minutes, a new text gets inserted into the database.

At the moment, my task is to find duplicates. However, I can't compare the texts using the comparison operator `==` as in many cases there have been made small changes to the text.

My idea so far is to compare the incoming text with all the other texts using the PHP function `similar_text` and add a relationship to texts that are almost 100% alike.

**The problem:** `similar_text` uses a very expensive algorithm. Therefore, one comparison between two texts with approx. 10,000+ characters takes over 0.1 second. That means that comparing one text with all the other texts takes 75,000 * 0.1 = 7500 seconds = 125 minutes. That is way too long because after two minutes I already receive the next text that I have to compare as well.

How can I speed this process up? Is there a quicker way to calculate the similarity of two texts? Or do you have other ideas on how I can find similar texts?

Comment: how about storingthe SOUNDEX value for each string and compare those

Comment: Sounds interessting, didn't know about that. I will make some tests tomorrow morning to see whether this method is reliable enough.

Comment: @Dagon It seems like the SOUNDEX value is too inaccurate for comparison. Due to the SOUNDEX value just having 4 characters, too many texts fall under the same category. Do you guys have any other ideas?